# XMPP Unsuscribe/subscription state leaks privacy

Tags: xmpp, privacy

I'm starting to work with XMPP, and one of the things that stood out right away to me was the fact that since subscriptions can be in just one directions, the roster can have a contact with a subscribe state of:

-none
-To
-From
-Both

The problem I have with this model is that a user can tell if someone "blocked" them (unsubscribed),  hasn't approved a subscription or isnt subscribed back.

Looking at it from the messenger style, if you don't approve a subscription or remove one, you its seen as if it they had approved the subscription, but just send offline presence.

Also on the removal, XMPP states that the server must tell the contact client that you have unsubscribed from them. I know most clients wont act upon this, but it means they COULD pop up something akin to "X contact has removed you from their list". Which I think is a privacy leak. If I want to block/remove people I'd prefer them not to know and just see me offline.

**Is there a specific reason of why this is this way? Is there an official way to get around it (not exposing subscription status)?**

Answer (score 0):

From a certain perspective, it's just always just been like this, mostly because the early Jabber developers all took the perspective that you should just say "no" when someone asked to see your presence, unless you were sure.

That said, you can use [Privacy Lists](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html) to block your outgoing presence.